# Azure DocumentDB parameterized stored procedure

Tags: node.js, sql-injection, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Looking for the correct way to parameterizing my stored procedures to avoid injection attacks. I can pass a parameter in similar fashion like "prefix", but not sure what the correct of handling the @id without doing something like "id=" + id, which leads back to avoiding injection attacks.

```
var sproc= 'dbs/{db}/colls/{col}/sprocs/GetDocument';
var  parameters = [
   {
            name: '@id',
            value: 'AndersenFamily'
   }
]

client.executeStoredProcedure(sproc,parameters , function (err, results, responseHeaders) {
            console.log('//////////////////////////////////');
            if (err) {
                console.log('// err');
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (responseHeaders) {
                console.log('// responseHeaders');
                console.log(responseHeaders);
            }
            if (results) {
                console.log('// results');
                console.log(results);
            }
            console.log('//////////////////////////////////');
});

// STORED PROCEDURE
function GetDocument(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id=@id',
        function (err, doc, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
            // else take 1st element from feed
            if (!doc || !doc.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody('no doc found');
            else getContext().getResponse().setBody(prefix + JSON.stringify(doc[0]));
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. A few things:

- I think you've confused the parameters of the sproc with the parameterization of the query.
- There is no need to throw an error or return an error string if isAccepted comes back false. There is some buffer time after you get a false to wrap up your sproc. In all likelihood, it'll finish in time, and if it's close you may get lucky and accomplish the return before it times out. If it forcebly times out, then DocuemntDB will return an error anyway.

So, you could do something like this:

```
var sprocLink = 'dbs/{db}/colls/{col}/sprocs/GetDocument';

client.executeStoredProcedure(sprokLink, "AndersenFamily" , function (err, results, responseHeaders) {
  console.log('//////////////////////////////////');
  if (err) {
    console.log('// err');
    console.log(err);
  }
  if (responseHeaders) {
    console.log('// responseHeaders');
    console.log(responseHeaders);
  }
  if (results) {
    console.log('// results');
    console.log(prefix + JSON.stringify(results));
  }
  console.log('//////////////////////////////////');
});
```

Stored Procedure:

```
function GetDocument(family) {
  var collection = getContext().getCollection();

  // Query documents and take 1st item.
  var parameters = [{name: '@id',  value: family}];
  var query = 'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id=@id';
  var querySpec = {query: query, parameters: parameters};
  var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    querySpec,
    function (err, doc, options) {
      if (err) throw err;
      return getContext().getResponse().setBody(doc[0]);
    });
}
```

If I understand your intent, there is no reason to pass `prefix` into the sproc. You can more efficiently add it when your are formatting your output upon returning from the sproc as I have shown above. If I've misunderstood your intent and you do want to use it for something inside the sproc, you can use an array `["AndersonFamily", "some prefix"]` or as an object `{name: "AndersonFamily", prefix: "some prefix"}` in place of the "AndersonFamily" that I show in my example above.

I left your query as-is because it'll work this way, but if all you really want to do is to get one document by id, then it might be more efficient to just use `readDocument()` rather than `queryDocuments()`. I would run an experiment to see. If you switch to that approach you'll want to use id-based routing which means that you'll need the database and collection names passed into the sproc.

It won't matter in this case with such a highly selective query, but a robust sproc would deal with continuation tokens and even restarting the sproc execution.

Note, I haven't actually run the code above. I just made text edits so it's very possible I've gotten some syntax wrong, but this answer at least gives you the conceptual understanding to work that out.

Comment: Thanks again, Larry. The prefix doesn't hold any relevance and just what was provided by Microsoft as a sample. It looks like I have been writing the parameter in the wrong place and not in the stored procedure itself. I wonder if you might have a sample of the continuation token/restarting lying around. I'm struggling to find a lot of documentation on these things. Thanks again!

Comment: I've written up my recommended pattern [here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#pattern-for-writing-stored-procedures). If you follow this pattern and use documentdb-utils, sprocs will automatically be restarted if they are forcedly timed out. If you'd rather not use all of documentdb-utils, the code to do this restarting is found in the wrapExecuteStoredProcedure() method currently found [here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/src/WrappedClient.coffee#L186-L218).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you once again.